# Is this the correct equation for "the probability that an event occur at least $x$ times"?

Tags: probability, statistics, proof-verification

In a situation, $n$ samples are drawn, each has a probability of $p$ to evaluate true for a certain criterion. The goal is to find a general formula calculating the probability for "at least $x$ number of the samples to be true."

Work so far:

Probability that exactly $0$ sample is true:
$$P(0) = (1-p)^{n}$$

Probability that exactly $1$ sample is true:
$$P(1) =(p)^1(1-p)^{n-1}$$

Probability that exactly $a$ samples are true:
$$P(a) =\binom{n}a(p)^a(1-p)^{n-a}$$

Probability that at least $2$ samples are true:
\begin{align}M(2)&=P(2)+P(3)+\ldots+P(n)\\
&= \sum_{i=2}^{n}{P(i)} \\
&= \sum_{i=2}^{n}{\binom{p}i(p)^i(1-p)^{n-i}} \end{align}

which, leads to the general formula of:

$$M(x) = \sum_{i=x}^{n}{\binom{p}i(p)^i(1-p)^{n-i}}$$

Which also inconveniently seem to have no simplification.

Comment: I tried to tag this as "solution verification", not sure why it shows up as "proof verification"

Comment: Assuming independence, the probability that exactly $a$ samples are true: $P(a) ={n \choose a}p^a(1-p)^{n-a}$ so the probability that exactly $1$ sample is  true: $P(1) =np(1-p)^{n-1}$ etc

Comment: Okay, editing now.

Comment: It's due to tag synonym

Comment: I will point out that in the scenario that you draw only $n$ times, it is impossible for there to have been $n+1$ or more occurrences seen implying your answer should have been zero, so you should have been immediately suspicious of your original attempt.

Comment: @JMoravitz not sure if the edit changes anything, also, I fear that I do not have the sort of intuition to quickly consider possible outputs and whether they are reasonable without actual calculation.

Comment: Event can't occur 2 times, it either occurs or not occurs. The title of the question should be smth like "Probability of event that at least $x$ samples are true".

Answer (score 0):

Let $X$ denote the number of the samples that are evaluated to be true out of $n$ samples.

Then $X$ follows binomial distrbuition, that is $X \sim Bin(n,p)$.

$$Pr(X \ge x) = \begin{cases} \sum_{i=x}^n \binom{\color{red}n}{x}p^i (1-p)^{n-i} & ,x \leq n \\ 0&, x > n\end{cases}$$